# Retrieving JPA entities causes updates in database

Tags: persistence

I have an EJB method.

```
    public List<Rfsprsus> findAll() {
    List<Rfsprsus> rl = getEntityManager()
            .createNamedQuery("Rfsprsus.findAll", Rfsprsus.class)
            .getResultList();

    for(Rfsprsus r: rl) {
        StringBuilder tempPwd = new StringBuilder("");
        for(int i = 0; i < paramFacade.find().getPwlength(); i++) {
            tempPwd.append("a");
        }
        r.setPassword(tempPwd.toString());
        if(r.getOrg() == null) r.setOrg(orgFacade.find("011"));         }
    return rl;
```

But, after invoking this method, then I check the database. I'm quite surprised that the **for loop actually caused an update**!

I don't know how and why, please explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added this on top of the method.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

r is an entity comming from the database.  When you modify it, you ask JPA to modify the database too.

Philosophically, don't consider JPA as a component which accesses a database.  Consider it as if all your entitys exist in memory, and JPA finds them when you need too.  The fact that JPA flushes these entitys to a database if you're not using them is mostly an implementation detail.

NOTE: When I say 'in memory', don't forget that it's a transactional kind of memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is because you are handling *attached* entities that are within an active transaction.

That is, they are still being managed by the entity manager. Entities that are managed by the entity manager and are part of an ongoing transaction act like a live link to the database. If you start a transaction, retrieve some data from the database, then you change the objects data by say using a setter, and then close the transaction it will have updated the database. You don't need the persist or merge commands in these cases.

If you want to manipulate the data returned from the database but not update the database, detach the entity or use a DTO (data transfer object). That is, change the data outside the scope of the transaction or by transferring the data into an object that isn't managed by the entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

The update may happen between these lines:

```
r.setPassword(tempPwd.toString()); 
if(r.getOrg() == null) r.setOrg(orgFacade.find("011"));
```

First you are updating entity `r` in memory. I'm not sure what `orgFacade.find()` does, but I guess it queries the DB. JPA, before executing the query,flushes pending changes to DB, just in case the query "touches" the already updated object `r` (note that everything gets executed in one transaction). So I guess the password is updated in DB as a side effect of `orgFacade.find()`.
The solution may be simple, just change the order of the aforementioned lines:

```
if(r.getOrg() == null) r.setOrg(orgFacade.find("011"));
r.setPassword(tempPwd.toString());
```